# move two layers together with jcanvas

Tags: html5-canvas, jcanvas

using [jcanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs), how do i link two draggable layers such that they move together.

[image]

eg. the circle and document icon are two diff layers. how do i have them 

a) draw on the same layer or 
b) move together

```
  // document
      .drawArc({
      layer: true,
      groups: ['document'],
      fillStyle: 'yellow',
      x: 100, y: 250,
      radius: 50
      })

      .drawImage({
      groups: ['document'],
      source: "img/document.jpg",
      x: 100, y: 250,
      width:40, height: 40,
      layer: true
    })


    $('canvas').setLayerGroup('document', {
      draggable: true,
      bringToFront: true
    })
```

Comment: my solution was to use svg images instead of drawing the parts separately.
perhaps someone else can suggest an answer to the question. the documentation doesnt make this use case clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `dragGroups:[]`

Code here

```
    $('canvas').drawArc({
            layer: true,
            groups: ['document'],
            dragGroups: ['document'],
            draggable: true,
            fillStyle: 'yellow',
            x: 100, y: 250,
            radius: 50
        })

        .drawImage({
            groups: ['document'],
            dragGroups: ['document'],
            draggable: true,
            source: "img/document.jpg",
            x: 100, y: 250,
            width: 40, height: 40,
            layer: true
        }).drawLayers();
```